# GCM push notification with C# asp.net giving null as notification in android devices

Tags: c#, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating a class in C# which has a method to send push notification in android using GCM. The method is working well and also giving response from google as success. But in the android emulator the notification is coming as null.
Here is the code I am using,

```
public void NotifyTest(string regId)
    {
        var applicationID = "AIza*************"; 

        var SENDER_ID = "xxxxxxxxxx"; 
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: key={0}", SENDER_ID));
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"registration_ids\":[\""+ regId +"\"]," +
                        "\"data\": { \"score\" : \"1234\"}}";
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is working without any errors and returning the response from Google too. Please let me know the suggestions.

Comment: What does the code look like in your Android app? Which part of the message is null?

Comment: @selsine thanks for the comment. I got it solved. In the android app code, it was using a key for retrieving the data which I found mismatched. When I changed it to the actual key given in android app then I got the real message.

Comment: Hi Vinod T G, I am getting the message as null. What shall I have to change? Please help. If you share the android application, It help me a lot.

Comment: Check This Link
[enter link description here][1]

Happy Coading:)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355528/gcm-push-notification-with-c-sharp-asp-net-giving-null-as-notification-in-androi/24187014#24187014

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the json string as below & modify your Android code for the get message & name.

string json = "{\"registration_ids\":[\"" + regId + "\"]," + "\"data\": { \"message\" : \"1234\", \"name\": \"Arvind Sharma\"}}";

Comment: We can use any data we want in the json string provided we use the same key both in the server side as well as the android side.

Answer (score 0):

In Android OnMessage(in GCMIntent service) write folowin line

```
  String message = intent.getStringExtra("score");
```

Happy Coading:)